# haproxy: close or change port 80 of stats page

Tags: configuration, http, haproxy, port, stats

The http-port has to be available for another usage.
Port 80 of the stats-page has to be closed or moved to another port.
Removing `mode http` in the `default` section disables the page.
`echo >/dev/tcp/hostname/80` returns '0' -> port 80 is already reachable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You havent posted your HAProxy config file?

You should just be able to specify what port you want the stats on i.e.

```
listen stats
bind *:8080
        mode http
        option forwardfor
        option httpclose
        stats enable
        stats show-legends
        stats refresh 5s
        stats uri /stats
        stats realm Haproxy\ Statistics
        stats auth loadbalancer:loadbalancer
        stats admin
```

Which you would access with username 'loadbalancer' and password of 'loadbalancer' at the url:

http://myipaddress:8080/stats

Comment: Thanks for your sample. This method is, what I've been looking for.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
listen stats
  bind *:9010
  bind :::9010 v6only
  mode http
  option forwardfor
  option httpclose
  stats enable
  stats uri     /stats
  stats refresh 5s
  stats show-legends
  stats realm Haproxy\ Statistics
  stats auth loadbalancer:loadbalancer
```